# How to write python script in flask

Tags: python, html, input, flask, cgi

I have problem about my python script with HTML.

I'm newbie.

My python script looks as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html>")
print("<head>")
print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
print("</head>")
print("<body>")
print("<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name))
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

and my HTML file:

```
<form action="hello_get.py" method="get">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />

Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I run HTML and write to input first name and last name, but my script doesn't start. It's just show the windows If I want to open script, or save it.

EDIT:

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <p>Want to get in touch with me? Fill out the form below to send me a message and I will try to get back to you within 24 hours!</p>
            <!-- Contact Form - Enter your email address on line 19 of the mail/contact_me.php file to make this form work. -->
            <!-- WARNING: Some web hosts do not allow emails to be sent through forms to common mail hosts like Gmail or Yahoo. It's recommended that you use a private domain email address! -->
            <!-- NOTE: To use the contact form, your site must be on a live web host with PHP! The form will not work locally! -->

            <form action="/app/get.cgi" method="get">
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Odoslať</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(my python script) get.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
file = open('file.txt', mode='w')
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = form.getvalue('name')
email = form.getvalue('email')
message = form.getvalue('message')

file.write(name) 
file.write(email)
file.write(message)

file.close()
```

and my app.py which is main flask module

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mypa$$w0rd'

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about.html')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


@app.route('/contact.html')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')


@app.route('/post.html')
def sample_post():
    return render_template('post.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm running it as localhost. 
Output when i click on SEND(in my html it equals ODOSLAT in my language):
Not Found

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

And text field in browser search now looks like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/app/get.cgi?name=asdf&email=julo.marko%40gmail.com&message=asfasfasf

Comment: Did you set up your web server to run python scripts?  Is your script marked as executable?  Scripts are usually named with a `.cgi` extension.  Did you try that?

Comment: @JohnGordon look at my edited post please.

Comment: @Reti43 look at my edited post please.

Comment: Your `get.cgi` script appears to be completely standalone, with no connection to Flask.  If your webserver is expecting all URLs to be handled by Flask, then that would explain the Not Found error.

Comment: Also, your HTML has `<form action="/app/get.py"`.  What is the file actually named?  `.py` or `.cgi`?  And where is it located?  Is it in `$WEBROOT/app/`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I forgot to change name, but it doesn't work anyway. Yes, It is located at project_juda which is the highest level directory with project where is /app and /env and get.cgi is in /app

Comment: Solution is place everything to flask form method. No any another scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Flask web application, you don't need any .cgi scripts. Just point your form to the appropriate route in flask. With the url in your html:

```
@app.route('/api/get.cgi')
def api_get():
    first_name = request.args.get('first_name')
    last_name = request.args.get('last_name')
    return """<html><body><h2>Hello %s %s</h2></body></html>""" % (first_name, last_name)
```

Comment: probably offtopic question but it's in this code and doesn't work, why it doesn't write it to the file.txt defined in my get.cgi script?

Comment: `/api/get.cgi` is only a name, and has nothing to do with any file called `get.cgi`. If you need some other action, you have to write it in the functions of your flask application.